# Are matrices $A$ and $B$ similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

> Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$ and let $B$ be the matrix you get by permuting the first and second columns of $A$, i.e., $$B = \begin{bmatrix} b & a\\ d & c \end{bmatrix}$$ Are matrices $A$ and $B$ similar?

I know that by multiplying $A$ by the elementary matrix for column permutation, you get

$$A \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} =  B$$

but I want to know if you can find $P \in \mbox{GM}_2(\mathbb R)$ such that $B = P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: I don’t think so. Take for example the identity matrix and that one you used switch the columns. One has only 1 as eigenvalues while the other one has i and -i as eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are almost never similar. In fact, if $\det A\neq0$, then, since $\det B=-\det A$, they are *not* similar.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm wondering if I take for instance a 4x4 matrix and the matrix I get by applying two permutations on the columns, the determinant doesn't change. I know that's not a sufficient condition but are they similar?

Comment: Yes, the determinant doesn't change. But the trace almost surely does and so, again, the answer is negative,